# Python check if date is within 24 hours

Tags: python

I have been trying some code for this, but I can't seem to completely wrap my head around it.

I have a set date, `set_date` which is just some random date as you'd expect and that one is just data I get.
Now I would like some error function that raises an error if `datetime.now()` is within 24 hours of the `set_date`.

I have been trying code with the `timedelta(hours=24)`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
if now < (set_date - timedelta(hours=24)):
    raise ValidationError('')
```

I'm not sure whats right to do with this, what the good way to do is. How exactly do I check if the current time is 24 hours before the set date?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like that?

```
if now-timedelta(hours=24) <= set_date <= now:
    ... #date less than 24 hours in the past
```

If you want to check for the date to be within 24 hours on either side:

```
if now-timedelta(hours=24) <= set_date <= now+timedelta(hours=24):
    ... #date within 24 hours
```

Comment: Something like this is what I am looking for yeah, but then to check for in the future. Check if `datetime.now()` is within 24 hours of `set_date` (assuming that is indeed in the future) @L3viathan

Comment: Then just add the timedelta to now on the right side.

Comment: For copy paste maniacs the missing imports are : `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`. The `now` variable is created this way : `now = datetime.now()`

Answer (score 16):

To check if the date is within 24 hours.

Take a difference between the current time and the past time and check if the no. of days is zero.

```
past_date = datetime(2018, 6, 6, 5, 27, 28, 369051)

difference = datetime.utcnow() - past_date

if difference.days == 0:
    print "date is within 24 hours"

## Also you can check the difference between two dates in seconds
total_seconds = (difference.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + difference.seconds
# Edited. Also difference have in-built method which will return the elapsed seconds.
total_seconds = difference.total_seconds()
```

You can check if total_seconds is less than the desired time

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as that:

```
from datetime import datetime

#...some code...
if (datetime.now() - pastDate).days > 1:
    print('24 hours have passed')
else:
    print('Date is within 24 hours!')
```

What you do here is subtract the old date `pastDate` from the current date `datetime.now()`, which gives you a time delta `datetime.timedelta(...)` object. This object stores the number of days, seconds and microseconds which have passed since the old date.

Comment: this is a great way to do it

Comment: probably need >= 1 otherwise it will only work after 48 hours will passed.

Comment: No, actually the above condition in `if` tells that 24 hours have 'passed'. The `else` will include the case when date is within 24 hours. There are other ways to do it as well. @ShaiKatz

Answer (score 1):

That will do:

```
if now - timedelta(hours=24) <= set_date <= now + timedelta(hours=24):
    #Do something
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if now - timedelta(hours=24) <= set_date <= now or now <= set_date <= now + timedelta(hours=24):
    #                           ---^--- in the past 24h  ---^--- in the future 24h
    #Do something
```